# glibtoolize on MacOS tells me to consider adding `-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS, but that produces an error

Tags: macos, libtool

I am trying to get libtool working on my MacOS 10.8.3 machine. Because everything Apple ships is out of date, I'm using macports. I have up-to-date versions:

```
libtool (GNU libtool) 2.4.2
automake (GNU automake) 1.13.1
autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.69
```

It's all installed in /opt.

Here is configure.ac:

```
AC_INIT([Hello], [0.1], [bug-report@hello.example.com], [hello], [http://hello.example.com/])
AC_PREREQ([2.59])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.10 no-define])
LT_INIT
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Here is Makefile.am:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libsomething-1.0.la
libsomething_1_0_la_SOURCES = something.cc


bin_PROGRAMS = hello
hello_SOURCES = hello.h hello.cc main.cc
```

Running glibtoolize produces this error:

```
glibtoolize: Consider adding `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])' to configure.ac and
glibtoolize: rerunning glibtoolize, to keep the correct libtool macros in-tree.
glibtoolize: Consider adding `-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
```

When I add this line to Makefile.am:
    ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS="-I m4"
I get this error;

```
glibtoolize: Consider adding `-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
```

If I change it to this:
    ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS="-Im4"

I get the same error:
    glibtoolize: Consider adding `-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.

The second error I get is:

```
 configure.ac:5: error: required file '../ltmain.sh' not found
```

How do I make these errors go away?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It needs to be:

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4
```

in `Makefile.am` and:

```
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
```

in `configure.ac`.  You do have an `m4` directory, at `$(top_srcdir)` right?

Comment: The spaces worked! How odd. How unusual. Now I just have this error: 
``configure.ac:5: error: required file '../ltmain.sh' not found` 
`autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1`

Comment: `autoreconf -fvi` should take care of that.

Comment: The system was corrupt! I'm not having this problem on another mac. Time to nuke `/opt/`

Comment: Whenever I would build stuff with autotools on the Mac, I always compiled and installed autotools from the latest GNU sources, since the ones shipped on the Mac were _always_ too old to build for the Mac.

Comment: I did that! I'm using macports. But macports doesn't build consistently, it seems.

Comment: this is like buried treasure, took me forever to find but helped me to solve a very similar problem in building xenial sudo for ubuntu 12.04 because reasons.  You sir or ma'am are a gentleman or gentlewoman and a scholar.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm late to the part, the answer of @ldav1s is the solution, BUT I still had issues.
After some Googling, I found this: https://pete.akeo.ie/2010/12/that-darn-libtoolize-acconfigmacrodirm4.html

So, ldav1's answer + this worked for me:

```
dos2unix Makefile.am
```

And now it works!

Comment: I’m glad you got this to work, but dos2unix changes line-endings, so it seems that you probably downloaded the file on a Windows computer and then moved it to a Mac or something...

Comment: It sounds logical, but I did git clone https://github.com/dashesy/cc-tool.git So they probably used a wrong CRLF? Anyway, maybe it could help someone else on Mac or Linux